# PyGame - RaspberryPi 3b+ with a ps3 controller

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi3, playstation3

I am trying to use pygame with the raspberry pi to use a PlayStation 3 controller as an input for a car.
I have tested the controller with a demo code, and everything works fine. Then when I try to use it in my program, it reads 0.0 as the input, when the joysticks are moved. attached is my current code:

```
import pygame

class controller:
        def __init__(self):
                pygame.init()
                pygame.joystick.init()
                global joystick
                joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
                joystick.init()

        def get_value(self, axis):
                value = joystick.get_axis(axis)
                return value
control = controller()
val = control.get_value(0)
while True:
        print(val)
```

I am aware that this test is only for axis 0, but the output is still 0.0 for all axes.

Below, i have attached the demo code, where all the values are properly read.

```
import pygame, sys, time    #Imports Modules
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()#Initializes Pygame
pygame.joystick.init()
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()#Initializes Joystick

# get count of joysticks=1, axes=27, buttons=19 for DualShock 3

joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()
print("joystick_count")
print(joystick_count)
print("--------------")

numaxes = joystick.get_numaxes()
print("numaxes")
print(numaxes)
print("--------------")

numbuttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
print("numbuttons")
print(numbuttons)
print("--------------")

loopQuit = False
while loopQuit == False:

    # test joystick axes and prints values
    outstr = ""
    for i in range(0,4):
        axis = joystick.get_axis(i)
        outstr = outstr + str(i) + ":" + str(axis) + "|"
        print(outstr)

    # test controller buttons
    outstr = ""
    for i in range(0,numbuttons):
           button = joystick.get_button(i)
           outstr = outstr + str(i) + ":" + str(button) + "|"
    print(outstr)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
           loopQuit = True
       elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
               loopQuit = True
             
       # Returns Joystick Button Motion
       if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
        print("joy button down")
       if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
        print("joy button up")
       if event.type == pygame.JOYBALLMOTION:
        print("joy ball motion")
       # axis motion is movement of controller
       # dominates events when used
       if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
           # print("joy axis motion")

    time.sleep(0.01)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

any feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: The only difference seems to be this line: `global joystick`. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: I have tried removing the global, and I get an error, "NameError: global name 'joystick' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is losing the reference to the initialised joystick.  It needs to  maintain an internal link to it. Note the use of `self.` in the class below.  This keeps the reference inside the class, making "self.joystick" a [member variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable) of the class.  Python classes *need* the `self.` notation (unlike lots of (all?) other object orientated languages).  While  editing I changed some of the names to match the Python [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), I hope that's OK ;)

```
class Controller:
    def __init__( self, joy_index=0 ):
        pygame.joystick.init()                # is it OK to keep calling this?
        self.joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick( joy_index )
        self.joystick.init()

    def getAxisValue( self, axis ):
        value = self.joystick.get_axis( axis )
        return value
```

Maybe you left the extra code out of the question, but a PyGame program without an event loop will eventually lock up.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 300
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 300


class Controller:
    """ Class to interface with a Joystick """
    def __init__( self, joy_index=0 ):
        pygame.joystick.init()
        self.joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick( joy_index )
        self.joystick.init()

    def getAxisValue( self, axis ):
        value = self.joystick.get_axis( axis )
        return value


### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
clock  = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption( "Any Joy?" )    

# Talk to the Joystick
control = controller()

# Main loop
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Query the Joystick
    val = control.getAxisValue( 0 )
    print( "Joystick Axis: " + str( val ) )

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( (0,0,0) )
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have changed the code to utilize self. in the class. With just this change, the value is still 0.0. I am trying to understand the second part of the code you have provided. what does the window and clock do? I am simply using pygame to recieve a number and axis from the controller, which will eventually tell a car to move forward and backward.

Comment: @ShaneCourter - Pygame uses an event model.  If you stop processing events, the program will eventually stop.  Your OS may consider it "unresponsive".  Having the window, and the event-loop stops this from happening.

Comment: Awesome, It is now working.  Your help is much appreciated.